# Dynamically importing an XSLT inside another

Tags: xml, xslt, dynamic, import, include

In our work, we have a custom framework which helps us build quick and powerful pages for our client services. One of the components of this framework is a special "Detail" functionality, which allows you to select a specific item of a list, click on it and view its detail. This is done because the Detail component receives a predefined XML structure and parses it with an XSLT, which allows it to present the data in different data tabs, show images or sum specific data, among other features.

Our requirement is that we want to be able to add new tabs that exist outside the predefined XML structure, so for instance, we could add a custom made chart, or any other specific display of data.

To do this, we figured a possible solution would be to make special tab inside the predefined XML structure, with two new attributes:

- **type:** which tells the parent XSLT that this tab should not be parsed with the standard XSL transformation. (e.g.: "Literal")
- **transformationSource:** which tells the parent XSLT which new XSLT it should include/import to transform this specific tab. (e.g.:"newTransformation.xslt")

Is this possible to do dynamically? Something along this lines:

```
<div>
  <xsl:for-each select="Tab"> 
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@type='Literal'">
        <xsl:include href=<xsl:value-of select='@transformationSource'/> 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise> --do what it does everytime
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Data" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

We have two problems with this:

1. We can't do a `value-of xsl` command inside another xsl command
2. We can't use the include or import functionality in a non-root html component, which means that it can't be used inside a div, or a table or row or anything.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't always include the stylesheet module letting the processor to decide wich rule apply depending on patterns regarding that attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xsl:include and xsl:import declarations are always evaluated at compile-time: you can't execute the XSLT code until you've assembled all the stylesheet modules needed.

To create a customised version of a stylesheet S, you should write a "customization layer" as a module M that adds to or overrides the rules in S, and then you should make M import S. You should then run the transformation specifying M as your stylesheet.

If you really need to look at the XML before deciding how to build the stylesheet, then you need to create a pipeline in which the first step constructs the stylesheet and the second step executes it. You can do this using pipeline tools such as Xproc (or Orbeon or Cocoon or xmlsh or even Ant...)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful. It seems we are going to have to change quite a bit so it works the way we want. Good idea on the usage of different layers, that's the first thing we are going to try. Cheers!